# Bad performance of SQL query due to ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance

I have a query joining 4 tables with a lot of conditions in the WHERE clause. The query also includes ORDER BY clause on a numeric column. It takes 6 seconds to return which is too long and I need to speed it up. Surprisingly I found that if I remove the ORDER BY clause it takes 2 seconds. Why the order by makes so massive difference and how to optimize it? I am using SQL server 2005. Many thanks.

I cannot confirm that the ORDER BY makes big difference since I am clearing the execution plan cache. However can you shed light at how to speed this up a little bit? The query is as follows (for simplicity there is "SELECT *" but I am only selecting the ones I need).

```
SELECT *
FROM View_Product_Joined j 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OPR_PriceLookup] pl on pl.siteID = NodeSiteID and pl.skuid = j.skuid 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[OPR_InventoryRules] irp on irp.ID = pl.SkuID and irp.InventoryRulesType = 'Product'
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[OPR_InventoryRules] irs on irs.ID = pl.siteID and irs.InventoryRulesType = 'Store'
WHERE (((((SiteName = N'EcommerceSite') AND (Published = 1)) AND (DocumentCulture = N'en-GB')) AND (NodeAliasPath LIKE N'/Products/Cats/Computers/Computer-servers/%')) AND ((NodeSKUID IS NOT NULL) AND (SKUEnabled = 1) AND pl.PriceLookupID in (select TOP 1 PriceLookupID from OPR_PriceLookup pl2 where pl.skuid = pl2.skuid and (pl2.RoleID = -1 or pl2.RoleId = 13) order by pl2.RoleID desc))) 
ORDER BY NodeOrder ASC
```

Comment: Have you looked at the query plan?

Comment: try indexing the column that you are using in your ORDER BY clause (if you haven't already, that is)

Comment: Also make sure you clear the data/execution plan cache down between each test, else you could get skewed results (worst case scenario is they actually do perform the same, but the 2nd runs quicker as it's getting data from the cache).

Comment: Could you please post the table definitions as well? It's not clear which tables the fields belong to.

Comment: You aren't actually using select * in production code are you? You have joins so at a minimum you are sending data that is repeated which simply wastes network and server resources. Never select more columns than you actually need and do not select joined columns from more than one table.

Comment: In addition to the index suggestion, another thing that can affect performance drastically is the data type.  Ordering by an integer should be much faster than ordering by a date or even worse, a varchar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why the order by makes so massive difference and how to optimize it?

The `ORDER BY` needs to sort the resultset which may take long if it's big.

To optimize it, you may need to index the tables properly.

The index access path, however, has its drawbacks so it can even take longer.

If you have something other than equijoins in your query, or the ranged predicates (like `<`, `>` or `BETWEEN`, or `GROUP BY` clause), then the index used for `ORDER BY` may prevent the other indexes from being used.

If you post the query, I'll probably be able to tell you how to optimize it.

**Update:**

Rewrite the query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    View_Product_Joined j 
LEFT JOIN
        [dbo].[OPR_InventoryRules] irp
ON      irp.ID = j.skuid
        AND irp.InventoryRulesType = 'Product'
LEFT JOIN
        [dbo].[OPR_InventoryRules] irs
ON      irs.ID = j.NodeSiteID
        AND irs.InventoryRulesType = 'Store'
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 *
        FROM    OPR_PriceLookup pl
        WHERE   pl.siteID = j.NodeSiteID
                AND pl.skuid = j.skuid
                AND pl.RoleID IN (-1, 13)
        ORDER BY
                pl.RoleID desc
        ) pl
WHERE   SiteName = N'EcommerceSite'
        AND Published = 1
        AND DocumentCulture = N'en-GB'
        AND NodeAliasPath LIKE N'/Products/Cats/Computers/Computer-servers/%'
        AND NodeSKUID IS NOT NULL
        AND SKUEnabled = 1
ORDER BY
        NodeOrder ASC
```

The relation `View_Product_Joined`, as the name suggests, is probably a view.

Could you please post its definition?

If it is indexable, you may benefit from creating an index on `View_Product_Joined (SiteName, Published, DocumentCulture, SKUEnabled, NodeOrder)`.

Comment: In order to execute the query I had to add skuID and siteID as output of the cross apply query, and also give it an alias name. It's now much much faster but also returns about 40% of the records. Will have to investigate further.

Comment: `@David`: I corrected the query a little, please see the post update. Is `PriceLookupID` a `PRIMARY KEY` on `OPR_PriceLookup`?

Comment: I got it working and it much much faster. It's good to know about cross apply. Many thanks!