# Adding ORDER BY clause makes query take longer time to complete

Tags: sql, sql-server

Without adding `ORDER BY RenewalDate`, it's taking 1 second. While adding `ORDER BY` clause, it's taking 2.22 minutes.i did indexing on this coloumn but not improved performance.Pindex(Non-Unique,Non-Clustered)

How to use `ORDER BY` clause without degrading performance.

`RenewalDate (date, null)` -  this column with `ORDER BY` is causing the problem

Query:

```
select 
    LinkId,
    LinkName,
    CategoryId,
    ReportLinks
    SubmissionStatus,
    convert(nvarchar(18), LnkSubmsnDate) as LnkSubmsnDate,
    convert(nvarchar(18), LnkUpdateDate) as LnkUpdateDate,
    LnkSubmtdBy,
    K.KeyWord,
    RenewalDate
from tbl_Link L
left join Tbl_keywords K 
    on L.KeywordID = K.KeywordID
where 
    (SubmissionStatus = 'Approved' or SubmissionStatus = 'Waiting for Approval')
    and  LnkSubmtdBy ='swapna'
    and Convert(Char(4), LnkSubmsnDate, 100) in (
        select Convert(Char(4), LnkSubmsnDate, 100) 
        from tbl_Link
    )
order by 
    case when RenewalDate is null then 1 else 0 end,
    RenewalDate
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139980/bad-performance-of-sql-query-due-to-order-by-clause

Comment: Do you have index in your `RenewalDate` column ?

Comment: no . but just now done indexing, lets see what happens,
CREATE INDEX PIndex
ON tbl_Link (RenewalDate)

Comment: i have done indexing but no effect,Pindex(Non-Unique,Non-Clustered)

but no performance improved, same 2.22 min@JapzDivino

Comment: Can you post the execution plans of both queries, with and without the sort? Also, what exactly is this clause -- `Convert(Char(4), LnkSubmsnDate, 100) in (select Convert(Char(4), LnkSubmsnDate, 100) from tbl_Link)`-- supposed to be doing? How is it possible for any value in `tbl_Link.LnkSubmsnDate` not to satisfy this criteria? You are checking against the same column in the same table.

Comment: but the problem is while adding order by renewal date than only decreasing performance

Comment: I know it isn't the source of the issue, I was just curious. Since I can't post an accurate answer without seeing the execution plans, I figured I would point out some other ways to speed up the execution while I wait, such as redundant predicates in the where clause.

Comment: My guess is out of date statistics. With no order by I suspect SQL Server is doing a clustered index scan on `tbl_Link`, but when you order by `RenewalDate` SQL Server the additional cost of the sort is deemed to outweigh the cost of a bookmark lookup, so an index on this column is used, then a bookmark lookup (essentially a nested loop join) is used to retrieve the remaining values from the table. This is an expensive operation, and is likely the cause of the decreased performance. The execution plans would of course confirm or deny my suspicions.

Comment: but i have no idea about execution plans. i think u r right i have to make changes in other columns also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91555/discussion-between-garethd-and-krishna-mohan).

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with this, because it is checking `RenewalDate` row by row, if you want to use that maybe you can put an index in your `RenewalDate` column.

```
    case when RenewalDate is null then 1 else 0 end,
    RenewalDate
```

Comment: i removed - case when RenewalDate is null then 1 else 0 end,and added simply order by renewal date , still its taking 2.22 min. its problem with order by not with case@japz

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
and Convert(Char(4), LnkSubmsnDate, 100) in (
        select Convert(Char(4), LnkSubmsnDate, 100) 
        from tbl_Link
```

Use this:

```
and exists(
        select  (1)
        from tbl_Link TL
            where Convert(Char(4), TL.LnkSubmsnDate, 100) = Convert(Char(4), L.LnkSubmsnDate, 100))
```

Comment: `EXISTS` and `IN` when written in this manner are optimised in exactly the same way so this would make no difference whatsoever. In addition, it certainly would not explain why adding the `ORDER BY` makes the query slow, where without it the query is significantly faster.

Comment: sorry order by not causing problem. Convert(Char(4),LnkSubmsnDate,100) in (select Convert(Char(4),LnkSubmsnDate,100) from tbl_Link )

this part cuasing problem, this making slow

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a unique clustered index on both tables (created BEFORE you create any nonclustered indizes). Maybe `tbl_Link.LinkId` and `Tbl_keywords.KeywordID` are candidates for unique clustered index respectively to be your Primary Keys.

Nonclustered index at firs sight:
One on `tbl_Link.KeywordID`would be a good idea - because it's your JOIN column, your connection to table `Tbl_keywords`.

Further consider indexing the columns:

- `SubmissionStatus`
- `LnkSubmtdBy`
- `LnkSubmsnDate`
- `RenewalDate`

Please keep in mind: **NONCLUSTERED** Index will only perform well if they are **CREATED AFTER THE CLUSTERED INDEX**

Comment: The statement *"NONCLUSTERED Index will only perform well if they are CREATED AFTER THE CLUSTERED INDEX"* is not true. If there is no clustered index (heap table) then there is still a unique identifier for each row (RowID) to which the nonclustered index points, if anything this performs better than with a clustered index, certainly not worse.

Comment: if the table is heap table -> data are scattered ANYWHERE on your disk! you will never never never get good performance compared to a table with a primary key/unique clustered index. nonclustered index will fragment very quickly and be "useless"....

Comment: While I do not advocate the use of heap tables and would always recommend a clustered index, I also don't advocate misinformation. The data isn't scattered anywhere on the disk, it is still stored in pages in the same way a clustered index is, there is just no predefined order of the data, as such a rowid is required to find each row. [This answer on dba.stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9831/7257) has done some quite extensive testing on nonclustered indexes on heap tables and clustered tables, and in every operation other than update the heap table performed better.

Comment: The nonclustered index will work in almost exactly the same way on both tables, the difference being on a heap table, rather than storing the clustering key for lookups, it uses the combination of file id , page number and slot number in the heap. So fragmentation certainly isn't an issue. In fact, because it is storing the exact page location of the rows in question, it is faster, because with the clustering key, the clustered index still needs to be traversed to find the correct data page.

Comment: "This answer on dba.stackexchange" says to me: Select is compareable, all other operations are faster having a clustered index !?!?!?

Comment: Scroll down further and view the actual results, rather than the conclusions, it goes on to state - *"As we can see from the added results, the conclusions on the limited tests were not correct in every case. The results now indicate that the only statements which benefit from the clustered index are the update statements. The other statements are about 30% slower on the table with clustered index."*

Comment: before this becomes a religious war - have fun with heap tables having nonclustered index. what's funny: one answer below the one you love is this link, accurate title ;)   http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/

Comment: The article you have posted is a debate on the types of clustering key, whether to use a natural key or surrogate key, and if so whether to use GUID or integer. It is nothing to do with indexes on heap tables. As I have said above, I fully advocate the use of a clustered index, heap tables are few and far between in my databases, all I am saying is that your statement about nonclustered indexes only performing well if a clustered index exists is not true. I probably wouldn't have said anything if it wasn't in bold, it means it jumps out and will misinform others that view this page.

Comment: my original statement was: "if you have a table with BOTH, CLUSTERED AND NONCLUSTERED INDEX it's important to create the clustered index first". that's it - no misinformation at all. No one talked about heap tables with clustered index until you began this nonsense-debate that's leading nowhere, at least it's not solving the user's problem